# How can I test the case where invisible Recaptcha detects a suspicious user?

Tags: invisible-recaptcha

I plan to use Google's [invisible recaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible) to make sure bots don't sign up on my website. I think I followed all the instructions, but I want to test it to make sure it works and see how it looks. But I'm a human, so it just lets me click with no problems. Is there a way to make the invisible recaptcha think I'm a bot so I can test that experience on my site?

Comment: Perhaps wget or curl would register as bots?  Just a thought--not an area I know a lot about.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing your website through Tor. If you try using Google Search through Tor it will continuously offer you a reCAPTCHA, because bots are often using the IP addresses associated with Tor and Google knows this. I imagine it will work for your website as well.